# Edit the comment review fields in WooCommerce Product Review Pro

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use the WooCommerce Product Review Pro on my Website and like to change the Name & E-Mail fields.

See attachment:

[image]

---

Can anybody tell me how to change the structure (make the fields behind each other) and add a placeholder.

Thats how the fields looks in frontend:

```
<p class="form-row validate-required" id="review_author_field" data-priority="" style="display: block;">
    <label for="review_author" class="">Name&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="erforderlich">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="input-text " name="author" id="review_author" placeholder="" value="">
    </span>
</p>
<p class="form-row validate-required" id="review_email_field" data-priority="" style="display: block;">
    <label for="review_email" class="">E-Mail&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="erforderlich">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <input type="text" class="input-text " name="email" id="review_email" placeholder="" value="">
    </span>
</p>
```

---

UPDATE: this code comes from the template file of the plugin

```php
<?php if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && get_option( 'require_name_email' ) && ! get_option( 'comment_registration' ) ) : ?>
    <?php if ( ! isset( $fields['author'] ) ) : ?> 
    <?php $fields['author'] = array( 'label' => __( 'Name', 'woocommerce-product-reviews-pro' ), 'required' => true ); ?> 
    <?php endif; ?> 
    
    <?php if ( ! isset( $fields['email'] ) ) : ?>
    <?php $fields['email'] = array( 'label' => __( 'E-Mail', 'woocommerce-product-reviews-pro' ), 'required' => true ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Since you'll be using an additional plugin to add these fields to the product reviews, it depends on how this plugin is built. For example, these fields can be added via code or via a template file. Therefore, people who don't have this plugin will have a hard time answering your question. I therefore believe it is better to authorize your question to the developers of the plugin itself.

Comment: I understand, but I try my luck, because the PlugIn developer let no possibility to contact him. It seem that the plugin use WordPress default fields and I hope, somebody can help me to get this fields.

Comment: What I can recommend in this case is to search the plugin files (via a text / code editor) 
on field IDs or classes. That way you can find out where the code is generated from within the plugin and (perhaps) extra explanation: with a template file, how you can overwrite it or that there is a hook available to overwrite the output of the fields.

Comment: In general, you can find the following explanation at the top of template files This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/... I don't know if this is the case for this template file? if so, you can follow these steps and make any desired changes to the copy of the template file

Comment: Unfortunately there are no such information.

Comment: All I can do is refer to the [following](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-product-reviews-pro/#section-29). Further help will have to come from someone who has this plugin

Answer (score 0):

You should hook into the fields by using:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_checkout_fields_order' );
```

Then change the priority for the field you wish to change:

```
function change_checkout_fields_order( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['author']['priority'] = 4;
 
    return $fields ;
}
```

Note that the key selected here can differ from your situation. If you're not sure about what key you need you can always first `print_r()` what's in `$fields`.

Comment: Thanks you! Do you know how can I change the classes of the fields, delete the label or or add a placeholder?

Comment: Yes you can just use `class` instead of `priority`. You should probably use the following then: `$fields['billing']['author']['class'] .= 'extra-class';`. I'm not sure whether it's an array of multiple classes or that it is a single string. If it is an array use: `$fields['billing']['author']['class'][] = 'extra-class';` And the same probably goes for `placeholder`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I've just added this: 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'change_checkout_fields_order' );

function change_checkout_fields_order( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['author']['class'][] = 'extra-class';
    $fields['billing']['author']['placeholder'][] = 'Name';
 
    return $fields ;
}

and it's not worked :/

Comment: Where have you added it? And are you sure author is within billing fields? Have you printed `$fields` like I suggested in the initial answer?

Comment: I've added it to functions.php in the Child theme. The fields are in the comment/review section and I'm not sure if they are the same.